# Change the language of the formulas

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a macro to open a read only copie of a workbook. This workbook has formula’s in Spanish but when finish the macro execution it’s display every formula in English. I don’t know if there’s a update who change something inside the vba extension or something like that.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Excel shows formulas in the language you work in, so it's not the VBA changing the language, but Excel itself. This may be helpful: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/excel-functions-translator-f262d0c0-991c-485b-89b6-32cc8d326889 or online solution: https://en.excel-translator.de/translator/

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to change the setting in excel:

> File > Options > Language

[image: Excel Options]

Let us know if that works.